# Queue implementation using simple Array[] in java

Tags: java, arrays, queue

I have thought to implement a queue using simple Array[] in java. I want all the possible use cases which I should consider tackling.

The way I will be implementing it is by keeping a put reference pointer on the currently put() values index position. And a poll reference pointer pointing to currently poll() values index position.

#### One of the possible use cases that I considered:

*1.> No poll() operation will be done if the current push and poll reference pointers are pointing to the same location.*

What other use cases I should consider.

Comment: Do you want to use queue in multithreaded way?

Comment: Why using an array for a queue and not just use a queue?

Comment: Any ADT(Abstract Data Type) uses underlying basic data structure like Array provided by java or a node based implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You should consider no put will be allowed if queue is full.

2) You may have way to retrieve size of queue, that is number of elements in queue.

3) If you are going to use queue between threads, then you should consider thread-safety.

4) You may want to add additional operations like peek().

**EDIT**

The obvious queue implementation is like this:

```
public class ArrayQueue {
    /**
     * Array to store queue elements.
     */
    private Object [] queueArray;
    /**
     * Size of above array.
     */
    private int arraySize;
    /**
     * Position in array where next queue element will be inserted.
     */
    private int putPosition;
    /**
     * Position in array from which next queue element will be retrieved.
     */
    private int getPosition;
    /**
     * Current number of elements in queue.
     */
    private int currentSize;
    /**
     * Lock for thread safety.
     */
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public ArrayQueue(int size){
        if(size <= 0){
            // there must be queue of at least 1 element.
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        // initialize other things.
        queueArray = new Object[size];
        arraySize = size;
        putPosition = 0;
        getPosition = 0;
        currentSize = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Inserts element in queue.
     * If queue if full, then waits for queue to make empty room for element to insert.
     * @param object to insert.
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    public void put(Object object) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (lock) {
            // critical section.

            while(currentSize == arraySize){
                // queue is full, wait for someone to call get() to have empty room in queue.
                lock.wait();
            }

            // we have empty room in queue.

            // insert next element in queue.
            queueArray[putPosition] = object;

            // update position where next element will be inserted.
            putPosition = putPosition + 1;
            if(putPosition == arraySize){
                // we reached end of index bound, wrap index back to 0.
                putPosition = 0;
            }

            // update current size.
            currentSize = currentSize + 1;

            if(currentSize == 1){
                // queue was empty before, invoke any calls if blocked in get().
                lock.notify();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns next element from queue.
     * If queue is empty, waits for some element to be added in queue.
     * @return next element.
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    public Object get() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (lock) {
            // critical section.

            while(currentSize == 0){
                // queue is empty, wait.
                lock.wait();
            }

            // queue is not empty.

            // retrieve next element.
            Object object = queueArray[getPosition];

            // update position from where next element will be retreived.
            getPosition = getPosition + 1;
            if(getPosition == arraySize){
                getPosition = 0;
            }

            if(currentSize == arraySize){
                // queue was full before, invoke any calls if blocked in put().
                lock.notify();
            }

            // update current size.
            currentSize = currentSize - 1;

            // return element.
            return object;
        }
    }

    public int size(){
        synchronized (lock) {
            return currentSize;
        }
    }
}
```

Read the comments to understand how it works, the you can update add your operations.

Comment: Thanx for the reply, I want fixed sized queue implementation. All the consideration given by you are specification/definition of queue. I want considerations based on my implementation on a core level while using array as queue